# Confusion regarding the logarithm of identity function on simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Define  $D=\mathbb C-\{x+i(\sin x)|x\in (-\infty,0]\}$.

Clearly $D $ is simply connected domain, define
$f:D\to \mathbb C$ by
$$f(z)=z$$

We know that for if we have a non-vanishing holomorphic function on simply connected domain $ D $ then we have a holomorphic logarithm of that function (i.e. a holomorphic function $g$ on $D $ such that $e^g=f$ on $D$) .

Now I am confused what will my $g$ look in this case and how will it differ from the principal logarithm.

I understand $g'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ but that is not leading me anywhere.

Any help or reference shall be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment that got too long - not sure about $D$ as it seems you wanted $x\in (-\infty,0]$ - anyway assuming that and assuming you take the branch that gives the real logarithm on the positive axis, it is easy to see that for example in the right half-plane $f$ is the same as the principal value (identity theorem), while in the 2nd quadrant it is same above the curve $x+i(\sin x)$ and shifted by $-2\pi$ below (identity theorem above, continuity plus identity theorem applied for third quadrant below), while in the third quadrant it is same below the curve $x+i(\sin x)$ and shifted by $2\pi$ above (the same reasoning as for the second quadrant with above/below switched)

In particular on the negative axis it is $\pi$ in $(-(2k+1)\pi, -2k\pi)$ so $(-\pi,0), (-3\pi, -2\pi)$, etc and then by continuity when we go a little above/below the axis, and $-\pi$ in $(-(2k+2)\pi, -(2k+1)\pi)$, so $(-2\pi, -\pi), (-4\pi, -3\pi)$ and by continuity when we go a little  above/below there etc

Looking at the maximum values of $\sin x /x$ on $k\pi, (k+1)\pi$ one also sees that $\arg f \in (-\pi - \arctan \frac{2}{3\pi}, \pi + \arctan \frac{2}{\pi})$ so it is still a bounded function

Comment: Sorry for the typo and thanks.

Comment: happy to be of help - it seemed reasonable that $x\in (-\infty,0]$, though of course, one can argue sort of similarly about the branch where we take out $x\in [0,\infty)$ - now it will be related to the principal branch of say $\log (-z)$ and by and large same behavior will happen except that now the first and fourth quadrants (and the positive real axis) are where the shifts happen

Comment: So I guess the same thing would happen if I had eliminated any other curve so that the space left for me would be simply connected .I mean it would be equal to principal logarithm on an open set and then on other places it would differ by $2\pi$ . I wonder.. What will happen if I remove a spiral originating at the origin ?..

Comment: always one can get topological curiosities that can complicate issues, but for nice Jordan arcs that connect $0$ to $\infty$ you can always figure out what happens; now if you have a curve that intersects both the positive and negative axis infinitely many times, with larger and larger amplitudes (eg spiral) you will get an unbounded (argument) imaginary part because you will start "going around" with the argument